# html2pdf wrong page size and missing css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2pdf

Im using html2pdf ( https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf )
to convert a form to pdf onclick. The form itself is very complex and includes 4 pages of css/js/html. Im just trying to capture one page of that now.

The plugin does what i want, but the page size is wrong and some css is missing.
Online the end of the form looks like:
[End of page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCXJk.png)

The end of the generated pdf looks like this:
[End of page 1 pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWUT7.png)

The left and top margin is ok, right and bottom are not fitting and the whole text is a little too big on pdf.
Maybe sth like a code to make the whole image size smaller would help to get all back on one page, since the original also has smaller text. Also as you can see, the blue frames around the text are missing. I guess thats css.

My code looks like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/master/dist/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <script>
      function printPDF() {
          var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
 html2pdf(element, {
     hmargin:       -0.60, 
  vmargin:       20, 
     filename:     'myfile.pdf',
     image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
     html2canvas:  { dpi: 192, letterRendering: true },
     jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait'}
 
});
   }
 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include this styling somewhere,  `overflow: 'linebreak',`
If you dealing with tables I would suggest `jspdf autotable` as well

Comment: overflow: 'linebreak', doesnt work when integrated in the script, nothing happens or the script stops working at all.

Comment: Well would suggesting then resizing the whole body or whatever that whole form is,  so it would fit into your one page or make the size of the pdf bigger.

Comment: You can use this `doc.internal.pageSize.height;` this takes the height of the PDF and you can place you element depending on the height. e.g. Set the height of you element by using something like this `doc.internal.pageSize.height - 30`

Comment: I tried integrating this below "function print to pdf" as " var height = document.internal.pageSize.height -30 ", but it prevents the script from working. Maybe i just placed the code wrong, im new to js

Comment: Well you cant just set `var height` and expect it to work, you need to apply it to css as well. And dont just say that it doesnt work, provide the error message. Now you need to find out how to change element height using js.